# Why does Gluster volume mount with only half capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, glusterfs

Problem: A Distributed-Replicate Gluster volume only has half capacity.

I set up AWS EC2 instances as a Gluster volume, and a third EC2 instance that mount the Gluster volume.

Both Gluster servers have two bricks of 2G each.  The Gluster volume is set up with replication factor 2, with the intention that the two servers hold 4G of identical data.  Here is the output from querying on one of the Gluster servers:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-167:~$ sudo gluster volume info

Volume Name: swarm
Type: Distributed-Replicate
Volume ID: 142a9406-f3c9-49c8-a38f-f55e85185d1a
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 2 x 2 = 4
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: ip-172-31-10-167.eu-west-1.compute.internal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick0
Brick2: ip-172-31-28-55.eu-west-1.compute.internal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick0
Brick3: ip-172-31-10-167.eu-west-1.compute.internal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick1
Brick4: ip-172-31-28-55.eu-west-1.compute.internal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick1
Options Reconfigured:
auth.allow: *
transport.address-family: inet
nfs.disable: on
performance.client-io-threads: off
ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-167:~$ sudo gluster volume status
Status of volume: swarm
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick ip-172-31-10-167.eu-west-1.compute.in
ternal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick0           49152     0          Y       15345
Brick ip-172-31-28-55.eu-west-1.compute.int
ernal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick0            49152     0          Y       14176
Brick ip-172-31-10-167.eu-west-1.compute.in
ternal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick1           49153     0          Y       15366
Brick ip-172-31-28-55.eu-west-1.compute.int
ernal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick1            49153     0          Y       14197
Self-heal Daemon on localhost               N/A       N/A        Y       15388
Self-heal Daemon on ip-172-31-28-55.eu-west
-1.compute.internal                         N/A       N/A        Y       14219

Task Status of Volume swarm
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active volume tasks

ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-167:~$ sudo gluster volume status swarm detail
Status of volume: swarm
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick                : Brick ip-172-31-10-167.eu-west-1.compute.internal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick0
TCP Port             : 49152               
RDMA Port            : 0                   
Online               : Y                   
Pid                  : 15345               
File System          : xfs                 
Device               : /dev/xvdb           
Mount Options        : rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
Inode Size           : 512                 
Disk Space Free      : 2.0GB               
Total Disk Space     : 2.0GB               
Inode Count          : 1048576             
Free Inodes          : 1048533             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick                : Brick ip-172-31-28-55.eu-west-1.compute.internal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick0
TCP Port             : 49152               
RDMA Port            : 0                   
Online               : Y                   
Pid                  : 14176               
File System          : xfs                 
Device               : /dev/xvdb           
Mount Options        : rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
Inode Size           : 512                 
Disk Space Free      : 2.0GB               
Total Disk Space     : 2.0GB               
Inode Count          : 1048576             
Free Inodes          : 1048533             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick                : Brick ip-172-31-10-167.eu-west-1.compute.internal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick1
TCP Port             : 49153               
RDMA Port            : 0                   
Online               : Y                   
Pid                  : 15366               
File System          : xfs                 
Device               : /dev/xvdb           
Mount Options        : rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
Inode Size           : 512                 
Disk Space Free      : 2.0GB               
Total Disk Space     : 2.0GB               
Inode Count          : 1048576             
Free Inodes          : 1048533             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick                : Brick ip-172-31-28-55.eu-west-1.compute.internal:/data/gluster/swarm/brick1
TCP Port             : 49153               
RDMA Port            : 0                   
Online               : Y                   
Pid                  : 14197               
File System          : xfs                 
Device               : /dev/xvdb           
Mount Options        : rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
Inode Size           : 512                 
Disk Space Free      : 2.0GB               
Total Disk Space     : 2.0GB               
Inode Count          : 1048576             
Free Inodes          : 1048533
```

So everything seems fine from the above.  But when I mount the volume on the third server, the volume shows that it only has a capacity of 2G instead of 4G:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-169:~$ mount
ip-172-31-10-167.eu-west-1.compute.internal:/swarm on /swarm/volumes/mytest type fuse.glusterfs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,max_read=131072,_netdev)

ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-169:~$ df -h
Filesystem                                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
ip-172-31-10-167.eu-west-1.compute.internal:/swarm  2.0G   53M  2.0G   3% /swarm/volumes/mytest
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-169:~$
```

And sure enough, the volume gets fills up if I write 2G to it.

If I create a bunch of small files at once, I can see that they distribute out between `brick0` and `brick1`.

All AWS EC2 instances are running Ubuntu LTS 16.04 AMD64 HVM EBS.  Gluster versions tried are 3.12.7 and 4.0.1.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

All the bricks are on the same "physical" disk device `/dev/xvdb`. You are aiming for **2 x replication**. On each server both bricks that are on that same server are on the same device. Because if the disk `/dev/xvdb` fails on one server, **all** the bricks on that server will have failed. With a replication of 2 this results in the total volume size that is half what you expected.
If you want the volume size to be 4G make one 4G brick on each server.
Or you can attach two different EBS block devices to your EC2 instances each. (Say /dev/xvdb and /dev/xbdc)

Off-topic: Another issue with this setup is that a third server is needed to be an arbiter to prevent [split brain](https://docs.gluster.org/en/main/Administrator-Guide/Split-brain-and-ways-to-deal-with-it/). For instance [thin arbiter](https://docs.gluster.org/en/main/Administrator-Guide/Thin-Arbiter-Volumes/) could run on the third EC2 instance that mounts the volume and help prevent split brain in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you did gluster volume create did you list the bricks like server.167/brick0 server.167/brick1 server.55/brick0 server.55/brick1

If it's the first case, with the replica set being on the same server, I'd wager the storage is cut in half on the server not the pool, becuase the server can't replicate more than 2GB.

If so rebuild the volume but list the bricks like 
server.167/brick0 server.55/brick0 server.167/brick1 server.55/brick1

Comment: Thanks, but no, that makes no difference.